# dash and local keyword not resetting shell

Tags: shell, variable, dash

[dash](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git) shell (unlike [bash](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git) and [busybox ash](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/shell) implementation where both examples print `foo: ''`) takes value of previously
defined variable, i.e.  guarding with local does not work:

```
$ foo=ee; bar() { local foo; echo "foo: '$foo'"; }; bar
foo: 'ee'
```

It requires declare it as empty:

```
$ foo=ee; bar() { local foo=; echo "foo: '$foo'"; }; bar
foo: ''
```

Is it a `dash` bug (worth of reporting) or `local` expect to initialize variable? The problem with local is that it's not POSIX, although there [was an attempt](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=767) ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493729/list-of-shells-that-support-local-keyword-for-defining-local-variables/493743#493743) which shows how different are `local` implementations in various shells).

Comment: IMHO, `local` only means "the changes to this variable should not be seen outside of the current scope".

Comment: I see this in my dash manpage: "When a variable is made local, it **inherits the initial value** and exported and readonly flags from the variable with the same name in the surrounding scope, if there is one." -- so, all working as designed.

Comment: In bash, to set a local valiue initialized to the outer scope value, we'd have to do `local foo=$foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior that you're observing is documented and what's expected in the `dash` shell.  It is not a bug.
From the `dash` shell's manual:

> When a variable is made `local`, it inherits the initial value and `exported`
> and `readonly` flags from the variable with the same name in the
> surrounding scope, if there is one.  Otherwise, the variable is initially
> unset.